# How to write a custom provider for EntityFramework.BulkInsert?

Tags: entity-framework, bulkinsert

I'm trying to use `EntityFramework.BulkInsert` with MySQL and it doesn't work out of the box like it does with a SQL database. From what the [documentation](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/documentation) says I have to write a custom provider for my database but I don't know how to do this nor can I find resource material.

So far all I wrote is this:

```
public class MySQLProvider : ProviderBase<MySqlConnection, MySqlTransaction>
{
        public override object GetSqlGeography(string wkt, int srid)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        protected override MySqlConnection CreateConnection()
        {
            return new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        }

        protected override string ConnectionString
        {
            get { return DbConnection.ConnectionString; }
        }

        public override void Run<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities, MySqlTransaction transaction, BulkInsertOptions options)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
}
```

I don't know what `GetSqlGeography` and `Run` are supposed to do so any help in writing this call is appreciated.

Comment: Look at the implementation in the current providers...

Comment: @ErikEJ do you know where I can find them?

Comment: https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: @ErikEJ I already red that

Comment: https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#branches/x.0.7/Src/EntityFramework.BulkInsert/Providers/EfSqlBulkInsertProviderWithMappedDataReader.cs